# Building upon SOC 2 Compliance of hosting provider

Tags: compliance, azure

We are looking at becoming SOC 2 compliant and I was curious if it is possible to leverage the compliance of a hosting provider as part of our attestation?  More specifically, our product is fully hosted in Azure datacenters - which are SOC-2 compliant - on their platform as a service (PaaS) offerings.  When it comes to infrastructure-related Trust Service Principals, would be be able to reference our host's compliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *When it comes to infrastructure-related Trust Service Principals, would be be able to reference our host's compliance?*

  Yes. You have the option to dedicate a portion of your audit to the vendor or sub-processor that meets the required controls. For instance, I have personally employed this approach with AWS, using their Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) for a project. In the audit, you would generally mark those specific sections as 'Not Applicable' and include a comment indicating that the controls are overseen by the vendor. A more pertinent question to consider is whether you have verified the necessary controls with your vendor in accordance with your vendor management policy. An auditor could ask for evidence in that regard.